Excel Countifs function with dates
been googling all day and really struggling to get my head around this one.
I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns but need to count the results of 3 sets of criteria that include a date range.  Columns essentially as below image

I want to count how many times the PERSON went to a specific PLACE in a MONTH
I want to simply use a pivot table to display the data but my boss wants the data laid out in a fixed table / sheet so he doesn't need to click anything.
Thanks in advance Gurus!

Rather than show a blank table, maybe use a Mark down table if you're really serious about wanting an answer. Less work for the people you're asking for free help from.

Your problem is that dates in Excel are a peculiar way of displaying a number. The text is a representation of a number - it isn't really there and cannot be matched!

@MartinBrown I disagree.

It's important to know if the date you need to match contains a time value as well. (It may not be displayed).

@MartinBrown - that's not even remotely true.

There is a number of ways of achieving your desired outcome, from very simple to really fun and sophisticated.  Since you are clearly a beginner, I would suggest doing it with a simple COUNTIFS formula, something like:
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Person's Name", B:B, "Specific Place", C:C, ">=Start Date", C:C, "<=End Date")

This is not a complete solution, you will need to make a couple of adjustments to make it work but it should set you on the right path.

That is great and keeps it simple (which i need lol), just to expand slightly is it possible to add in multiple criteria for one column for example                =COUNTIFS(A:A, "Person's Name", B:B, "Specific Place1",OR"Specific Place2",OR"Specific Place3", C:C, ">=Start Date", C:C, "<=End Date") ( have added in the word OR as an example not as part of the formula)

@Alantheprocrastinator - sure, have a look at - https://exceljet.net/formulas/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

This is almost a FAQ. It is a very common misconception about Dates and Times.
A similar question was asked about 3 months ago "FIND and LEN functions did not work in my Excel"
This is a simple demo for the OP of why he can't match dates with text.
It is about the simplest one that shows how a date/time is really just a special sort of number display format.
Today() Find        Find    
=TODAY()    20  =FIND(B2,A2)    54  =FIND(D2,A2)
=""&A2  20  =FIND(B3,A3)    54  =FIND(D3,A3)

Cut and paste that into Excel at cell A1 and you should see the canonical machine representation of TODAY() in Excel displayed below the Date formatted value of TODAY(). It is literally days since 0/1/1900 ie 1/1/1900 = 1. You can test this pretty easily enter 0 into a cell and then do "Format as date".
(GROAN) The TABs will have been suppressed so you will have to do Data Text_to_Columns with separator " " (space) for it to work.
It should look like this:

For some unfathomable reason Excel doesn't like dates before 0 and displays #######  (even though day number relative to 31/12/1899 is perfectly well defined for negative values).
Concatenating a troublesome value with an empty string is an effective way of finding out what Excel's internal representation of eg. dates/times looks like.
The OP's original problem can be solved by entering the start of a month dates as dates and then using their numerical values to control what to sum.
Day number is well ordered. Tagging the first of each month should suffice.
There is a corresponding one for numerical results as well. If you put an expression inside round brackets then it will be evaluated and displayed to full double precision rather than censored by Excel's 15 decimal digits rule.
